# Use of undeclared type 'UIImage' in Swift

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift, cgfloat, swift-playground

On using this function in swift and i am getting compiler error.
Function is:

```
class func imageWithImage (imageToResize : UIImage, scaledToSize newSize : CGSize) {
    return imageToResize;
}
```

and the error are:

1. Use of undeclared type 'UIImage'
2. Use of undeclared type 'CGSize'

What's wrong with this..? what can i do to use UIImage in Swift..?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Did you add `import UIKit` to your file?

Comment: Ohh... it is just silly mistake as not importing "UIkit" Because we don't have to import it manually in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I have run on this issue when duplicated a framework target on swift. As a result  and .h (that is umbrella[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481319/4770877) and is located in `Build Phases -> Headers`) were different(because it just copied from upstream target). The umbrella file contains `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

- Create `<new_framework_target_name>.h` and add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

  or
- Rename `Product Name` (`Build Settings`) as `upstream_framework_target_name`.h