# What is an umbrella header?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is basically an umbrella header? What is its use? I got a warning as shown below. What does this mean?

```
<module-includes>:1:1: warning: umbrella header for module 'XCTest' does not include header 'XCTextCase+AsynchronousTesting.h' [-Wincomplete-umbrella]
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Headers/XCTest.h"
```

Comment: is your project consists of cocoapods ?

Comment: no, am using cocoa touch

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The [umbrella header](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) is the 'master' header file for a framework. Its use is that you can write

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

instead of

```
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UILabel.h>
#import <UIKit/UIButton.h>
#import <UIKit/UIDatePicker.h>
```

and so on.

For me, `<XCTest/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.h>` is included in `<XCTest/XCTest.h>`. Maybe it is not for you? In that case, add the

```
#import <XCTest/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.h>
```

manually.

Comment: +1 for the documentation link, -1 for the explanation, which is wrong. UIKit is not an [umbrella framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-97623-BAJJHAJC).

Comment: `UIKit/UIkit.h` is the "master header file" of a standard (not umbrella) framework.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe XCTest is not an umbrella framework either. Apparently, the compiler calls it an 'umbrella header', while 'master header' would be a better description.

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't know what trickery goes on with XCTest and why clang emits the `-Wincomplete-umbrella`. But your explanation of what an umbrella header is does conflict with the documentation. A master header is not the same as an umbrella header.

Comment: To clarify a bit: @Glorfindel's description is correct and is *not* specific to an umbrella framework (which groups a set of frameworks) - *every* framework has an umbrella header (which groups public header includes) and by default has the same name as the framework, and if you need it to have a different name, [customise the modulemap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153383/618653)

Answer (score 13):

**Umbrella header**

`umbrella header` - iOS `framework` or `library` on `Objective-C` or `Swift` can have a header file that contains references to all the other headers in that project.

When you create a framework target Xcode will automatically generate `<targer_name.h>` file. It should has the same name as `PRODUCT_NAME`

For example `<umbrella_name.h>` looks like

```
#import "header_1.h"
#import "header_2.h"
```

or:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for SomeModule.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double SomeModuleVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for SomeModule.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char SomeModuleVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <SomeModule/PublicHeader.h>
```

As a result you can use the next syntax

```
#import <umbrella_name.h>
```

instead of

```
#import <header_1.h>
#import <header_2.h>
```

On practice when you create a `Framework` on `Objective-C`[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216086/4770877) or `Swift`[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216060/4770877) this file will be created automatically with `<product_name>`

**Using**

1.`umbrella header` is required by [[`.modulemap`]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213694/4770877) structure to use **module**(expose Objective-C headers) for Objective-C or Swift

2.`umbrella header` can be just used by Objective-C consumer for connivance

3.`umbrella header` helps to import every Objective-C header into Swift module that is why you can just skip `import`

> Swift sees every header you expose publicly in your umbrella header. The contents of the Objective-C files in that framework are automatically available from any Swift file within that framework target, with no import statements. Use classes and other declarations from your Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use for system classes.

[Importing `Objective-C` into `Swift` within a Framework Target](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)