# Renaming umbrella header

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a naming conflict with the Umbrella header. My framework name is "SecureData", but I want to have an objective-c class in this framework called "SecureData".

The problem is that the umbrella header has to be called "SecureData.h" and I can't figure out how to specify a different name for the umbrella header in xcode settings. Is this possible, or do I just need to come up with a different name?

Answer (score 20):

It's Possible.

You can specify a different name for the umbrella header by `Module Map File`.

1. Create new modulemap file for Project.

   ```
   framework module XXXProject {
      umbrella header "XXNewumbrellaName.h"

      export *
      module * { export * }
   }
   ```
2. Specify modulemap file: `Build Settings -> Packaging -> Module Map File`

Ok, You expected effect is achieved.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Note: name `module.modulemap` is recommended: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-maps

Comment: @Cœur It's recommended, but apparently also prevents your code from compiling :( https://twitter.com/charlesismcom/status/846615073737007104

Comment: @Cœur Xcode 8.3 Release notes: "When building a framework that has module maps in both the source and the install directories that define the same module, the compiler will show a redefinition message. (28638816)
Workaround: Rename the module map file in the source directory to a non-default name (the default name is module.modulemap or module.map), and set the Module Map File build setting to the renamed module map."

Comment: Oh lol. So after recommending it for years, they just broke it for anyone who followed the recommendation? http://www.openradar.me/30194818