# swift package manager 'cannot find target' error message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, socket.io, swift-package-manager

I am very new to package manager and can't seem to import a library correctly.  I am using the following code:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyAppName",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "MyAppName", targets: ["MyAppName"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift", .upToNextMinor(from: "13.1.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyAppName", dependencies: ["SocketIO"], path: "./Source Files")
    ]
)
```

After creating this file and placing it in my project main directory, I open a terminal window and type swift build.  The files are fetched however I get the following error message:

> could not find target(s): MyAppName; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path

I really don't understand the products and targets section of the package file and what I am doing wrong.  I just put my app "MyAppName" for the executable and target but don't quite understand if that is correct.  Also, not sure the path is correct.  I want the libraries to be added to a folder titled Source Files in my main project directory.

Answer (score 4):

Everything in your *Package.swift* looks fine, you only need to put *MyAppName* directory with the source files in one of the directories *Sources, Source, src, srcs* in the top-level directory.
So the top-level directory (the one where Package.swift is located) should have the following structure:

`TopLevelDirectory
  |- Package.swift
  |- Sources
       |- MyAppName
             |- MyAppNameSource1.swift
             |- MyAppNameSource2.swift`

Alternatively, you can add the 'path' property to the definition of the target "MyAppName" and to specify where the directory with the sources resides.

Reference: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md#target-format-reference

Comment: thanks for you reply.  I tried to add a path to my source files, but during the swift build from command line I get the error: 'swift:9:8: error: no such module 'UIKit' import UIKit' as it goes through my source files one by one.  not sure what is really happening there and why UIKit is being referenced or why it is going through my source files.  I guess my understanding of package manager and dependencies is very limited

Comment: You should check where in the source of MyAppName appear references to UIKit. UIKit is a client-side module, it is probably not ported to the server-side. Swift Package Manager is for the server-side code, to run on MacOS and Linux, in a command line.

Comment: I should have mentioned previously I am doing this on Xcode for an iOS project, not OS.  I wonder if that's the problem

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem. See this comment from February 2016 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778823/swift-package-manager-uikit-dependency#comment58685107_34779231

Answer (score 2):

This will be  dependencies:  inside

```
  .package(url: "https://github.com/Netvent/storyly-ios.git",
                      .upToNextMajor(from: "1.0.0"))// or `.upToNextMinor
```

and in target . you have to say .product

```
.target(name: "segmentify",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "Storyly", package: "storyly-ios")]),
```