# How can I build a Swift Package for iOS over command line?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

In Xcode, I can select my destination as a "generic iOS device" or any iOS simulator, and my package will build platform-specific code for ios.

Via command line "swift build" **only** builds my target for macOS.

I want to build the target for iOS for CI purposes. The problem with building for macOS is that UIKit-specific code won't be built.

For example:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
    // some invalid code
#endif
```

The invalid code will not be noticed and will pass the build phase.

Ideally, I could say something like `swift build -platform iOS`. Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At time of writing (Feb 16, 2019), a working solution is:

```
swift build -v \
    -Xswiftc "-sdk" \
    -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" \
    -Xswiftc "-target" \
    -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios13.0-simulator"
```

This command uses `-Xswiftc` to workaround the issue by overriding the sdk from macOS to iphonesimulator.

> Strictly we add these flags so developers can work around issues, but they also should report a bug so that we can provide a proper solution for their needs.

[Source](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/commit/d04ca889fc0ddafbec2c63511a3cd9570a43f5f7)

So I'm guessing there will be a more elegant solution in the future.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea how to make it work for mixed Swift/ObjC packages? The swift side of my library seems to build fine, but ObjC errors on importing UIKit

Comment: @powerj1984 I am doing a project rn with Swift+C (not ObjC), and might be hitting a similar issue. I think it has to do with the Linker. e.g. you are linking to a macOS binary when you should be specifying a link to an iOS binary. Check out the `swift build -Xlinker -L/<somepath>` command. I don't know the solution, but it's a starting point

Comment: Thanks Michael! If I get a chance I might look into it more. For now I just rewrote my ObjC code in Swift 

There was a trivial amount of ObjC in my library, so was pretty straight forward for me

Comment: When I run this command I get this error from dependency:
`error: the library 'XYZ' requires macos 10.13, but depends on the product 'Kingfisher' which requires macos 10.14; consider changing the library 'XYZ' to require macos 10.14 or later, or the product 'Kingfisher' to require macos 10.13 or earlier.
` any way to fix it?

Comment: @WojciechKulik i'm getting the same, have you found a solution?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin the solution is below - use `xcodebuild` instead of `swift build`. It supports swift packages :)

Answer (score 31):

Starting with Xcode 11, [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) supports SwiftPM packages out of the box.

An example invocation would look like this:

```sh
xcodebuild -scheme Foo \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 11 Pro'
```

where `Foo` would be the name of the library product you're trying to build. You can
get the full list of available schemes for you SwiftPM package with `xcodebuild -list`.
You can get the list of available destinations for a given scheme with this invocation:

```sh
xcodebuild -showdestinations -scheme Foo
```

Comment: does this require adding an Xcode project to the package?

EDIT: Nevermind, just tested it and it works fine without an Xcode project file!

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of headaches! Thanks.

Comment: How would you go from a destination (from `-showdestinations`, e.g. `{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FD90A730-A1D5-4BBC-B61A-0324400EE9EA, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }`) to a value to pass to `-destination`? I've been getting `xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier`

Comment: I think you pretty much have to remove braces and replace `:` between field names and field values with `=`. Then in your example it becomes `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=15.0,name=iPhone 12'`

Comment: Just got this to work with the following format | 

    `xcodebuild -scheme ProjectName -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=204FA3AF-347C-494D-B612-A3D8FE2C9660'`