# How to test a Swift Package, that uses UIKit?

Tags: ios, uikit, xctest, swift-package-manager

I've created my first Swift Package recently. It's only used in iOS currently, and if it goes anywhere else, it *might* be on tvOS, but that would be it.

I was having trouble getting UIKit to be used. And I saw this note over here, and that really helped solve my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684636/1435520

The command I used (and mentioned above) is this:

```
swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios13.0-simulator"
```

However, I'd really like to have unit tests. Running `swift test...` with the same arguments mentioned for `swift build`. But then that gives me a new error:

`error: module 'XCTest' was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-macos10.14`

So, I guess I'm just wondering if it's possible to do this. Like, how could I create a Swift Package, that uses UIKit, and have it be testable?

Comment: Could you rig up a sample?

Comment: @JonReid I have an example of a similar problem, with my [RudifaUtilPkg](https://github.com/rudifa/RudifaUtilPkg). The master branch contains no UIKit dependencies yet, and the workflow action `build_and_test` executes successfully. The new branch `rf-attributed-strings` depends on UIKit, and the action `build_and_test` fails (see [pull request #5](https://github.com/rudifa/RudifaUtilPkg/pull/5)) test details).

Comment: On my home mac I have been trying possible solutions along the lines mentioned by @DanMorrow, and I hit the same problem: ``swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator"`` succeeds while ``swift test -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator"`` fails with `... was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-macos10.15`.
Any helpful suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using the command `xcodebuild` as detailed [in this forum post](https://forums.swift.org/t/use-spm-to-build-ios-target/25436/10), which requires you to also generate a `.xcodeproj`:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
xcodebuild build -sdk iphoneos -scheme 'MyPackage-Package'
xcodebuild test -destination 'name=iPhone 11' -scheme 'MyPackage-Package'
```

But if you're using SPM Resources, you'll run into issues as I detailed here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13773

Answer (score 5):

I have spent a lot of time trying to run tests of some complex framework. None of the solutions have worked for me.

I found out that `generate-xcodeproj` is marked as deprecated.
The reason to that I have found [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/rfc-deprecating-generate-xcodeproj/42159).

"... starting Xcode 11, opening and building packages is directly supported by Xcode ..."

So I run `xcodebuild test` directly in the package folder, without creating the xcodeproj.

```
xcodebuild -scheme '<package name>-Package' -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air (4th generation),OS=15.0' test
```

And it have worked.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to build and test my internal packages on CI, nothing works for me, and generating an `xcodeproj` will be deprecated in the future.

What works for me is to just specify the target as macOS 10.15 by doing this without anything else:

```
swift test -Xswiftc -target -Xswiftc x86_64-apple-macosx10.15
```

Comment: This does not work for me because I'm using UIKit and I get the error `error: no such module 'UIKit'`. In this other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71382981/3012842 they say it's not possible to use "swift test" for iOS.