# Conditional compilation of Objective-C framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I’m developing an Objective-C framework and I need to be able to build 2 different versions of that framework:

- The basic framework,
- The basic framework + some extra functionalities (some of which are written in Swift).

In the header of my framework, I expose my public headers like this:

```
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader2.h>

#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader2.h>
```

So far, I created a second target for my framework with extra functionalities.

So I have my "basic framework" target with all the classes it needs referenced in the Build Phases tab of the target.
And I have my "framework with extra functionalities" target, with a few more classes referenced in the Build Phases tab of the target.

When I want to build the "basic framework", I select my "basic framework" target, and I edit the header of the framework to import only what's needed:

```
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader2.h>

//#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader1.h>
//#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader2.h>
```

When I want to build the "framework with extra functionalities", I select my "framework with extra functionalities" target, and I edit my framework header to import the headers I need:

```
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader2.h>

#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader2.h>
```

It works, I can build both versions of the framework and use them in my iOS projects.

But I would like it to be simpler than having to edit my framework header every time I switch targets.

I tried to define a preprocessor macro "EXTRAFUNCTIONALITIES=1" in my target's build settings, in Apple Clang - Preprocessing and in Custom Compiler Flags, so that I could just have my framework header like this:

```
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkPublicHeader2.h>

#if EXTRAFUNCTIONALITIES
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFramework/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader2.h>
#endif
```

But even though it compiles, the framework cannot be used on my iOS projects anymore when I do that (I have "Unresolved identifier" errors when trying to compile the app that uses my framework).

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative solution to have my framework header expose different public headers depending on the target selected?

Comment: Use different files for umbrella headers?

Comment: Thanks! It works! I posted an answer to indicate what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a different umbrella header file for each target, as suggested by Cy-4AH.

I tried it previously and it didn’t work. But now it does! Thank you!

The name of the umbrella header needs to match the product name (as indicated in [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481319/2670899)), and the import statements need to be updated with that product name, like so:

Product name: MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities

Umbrella header: MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities.h

```
#import <MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities/FrameworkPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities/FrameworkPublicHeader2.h>

#import <MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader1.h>
#import <MyFrameworkWithExtraFunctionalities/FrameworkExtraFunctionalityPublicHeader2.h>
```

When I tried previously to make a new umbrella header, I wasn’t giving it the same name as the product name, and the framework was still compiling well, but it wasn’t usable by my iOS projects.